# terminal window in web page with OCLIF

Tags: angular, xtermjs, oclif

I have an existing cli with OCLIF.  I'd like to embed the cli in an angular web application.  Is this possible?  How might I start this?  I started looking at xterm.js. Can these two technologies be combined?  If not OCLIF what other librbaries might I use to create a cli window in a web page?

Comment: On server side - use `node-pty` to spawn a pty with your cli command. On client side feed output of the pty to `Terminal.write` and terminal input back to the pty.